# Change AssemblyName of a csproject via msbuild

Tags: msbuild

I have a msbuild that calls a `*.sln` file when doing compilation. This solution file contains 10 csprojects, one of them ( let's call it `main.csproject`) has the `AssemblyName` as `WinMusic`. The content of the msbuild is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">


  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Default value here -->
    <DefineConstants Condition=" '$(DefineConstants)'==''" >TRACE</DefineConstants>   
    <SlnFiles Condition=" '$(SlnFiles)'==''" >FullProject.sln</SlnFiles>   
  </PropertyGroup>

 <!-- <ItemGroup>  -->
  <!--   <SlnFiles Include="SlnFiles=$(SlnFiles2)"/> -->
  <!-- </ItemGroup> -->

  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SlnFiles)"
                 Properties="DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

My question is, how to set the `AssemblyName` property from the above msbuild task?

Just to clarify, I'm talking about `AssemblyName` in csproject, not in `AssemblyInfo.cs`.

Edit: This is the new `build.proj` file I tried, the `FullProject.sln` is a solution file with one exe and one dll, but the msbuild file renamed both the dll and the exe to `NoMusic`. What I want is just to rename the exe to `NoMusic` and the dll should retain the same name.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">


  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Default value here -->
    <DefineConstants Condition=" '$(DefineConstants)'==''" >TRACE</DefineConstants>   
    <SlnFiles Condition=" '$(SlnFiles)'==''" >FullProject.sln</SlnFiles>   
  </PropertyGroup>


  <Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="$(SlnFiles)"
                 Properties="DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants)"/>

     <MSBuild Projects="WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1.csproj" 
         Properties="DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants);Platform=ANYCPU;AssemblyName=NoMusic"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 3):

Just do this:

```
<Target Name="Build">
    <MSBuild Projects="@(SlnFiles)"
             Properties="DefineConstants=$(DefineConstants)"/>

    <MSBuild Projects="main.csproject.csproj" 
         Properties="AssemblyName=NoMusic"/>
```

Love to know why though.

Comment: This way you're redefining property in the project similarly to `msbuild.exe main.csproject.csproj /p:AssemblyName=NoMusic` would do. Take a look at MSBuild documentation if you don't know what `/p` switch does.

Comment: [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/msbuild/thread/95a04398-05c1-4fea-b596-abbe156e6a84) is extensive information on property evaluation process in MSBuild.

Comment: @James, I don't think it works; if you have 2 projects ( one exe, another dll) inside your solution, then both of the dll and the exe will be renamed to `NoMusic`, which is obviously not what I want.