# Set the AssemblyName property of only one project in NAnt

Tags: c#, msbuild, clickonce, nant

I am developing a ClickOnce-deployed application and would like to split my releases into multiple builds (a "stable" release and a "test" release). I know that to keep my test and stable releases separate, I need to set the "AssemblyName" property to be different. Here is what my call to MSBuild looks like in my NAnt script:

```
<msbuild project="../MyProject/MyProject/MyProject.csproj" target="publish">
  <property name="Configuration" value="Release"/>
  <property name="ApplicationVersion" value="${buildnumber.version}"/>
  <property name="ProductName" value="My Project (Test)"/>
  <property name="AssemblyName" value="MyProjectTest"/>
  <property name="InstallUrl" value="http://www.mycompany.com/software/MyProjectTest/"/>
</msbuild>
```

However, one of the references of my project is a library which I also wrote myself. The reference is therefore to the `.csproj` file of the library instead of a DLL. The above MSBuild call seems to force the `AssemblyName` recursively down, setting the `AssemblyName` of my library project to also be "MyProjectTest", when I would like it to just be called "MyLibrary".

Here's a snippet from `MyProject.csproj` (ie. MyProject's MSBuild script), showing the reference to the library:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\..\MyLibrary\MyLibrary\MyLibrary.csproj">
    <Project>{A011B373-74D3-45EF-92E2-F342C572402A}</Project>
    <Name>MyLibrary</Name>
    <Private>True</Private>
  </ProjectReference>
</ItemGroup>
```

I have a few workarounds which might work, like building the library separately and then setting the reference to point to the compiled DLL instead of the `.csproj` file, or manually copying-and-pasting the properly-compiled version of the library over from the stable release's folder, but what I would really like is for NAnt to work properly.

So, I suppose my question is this: *Is there a way to force the `AssemblyName` of just one project using NAnt's `msbuild` task?*

*Edit: Another little note: Another fellow a few years ago had this same issue but never got a satisfactory solution. You can read the question (and relevant comment) here: [Change AssemblyName of a csproject via msbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996678/change-assemblyname-of-a-csproject-via-msbuild#comment8353672_6997225)*

Comment: There an [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15553524/msbuild-command-line-argument-at-project-level-not-solution-level-for-changing-a/15592458#15592458) that looks promising.  It means changing your csproj file, but it looks acceptable.

Comment: I am not opposed to changing the csproj file at all! This is exactly what I need. Thanks! If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'd rather just see this question closed as a duplicate of the other (and have voted as such!) - it's close enough that the solution there fits as it's msbuild specific rather than nant.  Good to leave this question here as a signpost to the other though.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to adjust similar things, I generally use `xmlpoke` or `loadfile`/`echo` to rewrite web.config or assemblyinfo.cs then run the msbuild task merely specifying the solution name.  You could also use [`#if MYTHING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y6tbswk.aspx) to conditionally define the AssemblyName inside assemblyinfo.cs then conditionally pass `<arg value='/p:DefineConstants=MYTHING' />` as part of the msbuild task.